# Linear Algebra, Linear Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> State if the given map is a linear operator from $V$ to $W$. Explain your answer.
>
> $V = W = \{f(x)\mid f(x) \text{ is a polynomial, degree of $f$ is } \le 5 \text{ and } f(1) = f′(1) = 0 \}$, $D(f) = (x − 1)2f′′$

Does anyone know how to set up this question?

Comment: If $f, g \in V$, does $D(f+g) = D(f) + D(g)$? For $r$ a real, does $D(rf) = rD(f)$? If so, it's a linear operator.

Comment: @BrianO It's a linear operator from where to where?

Comment: from $V$ to $W$ ($=V$)

Comment: Really? What is $D(x-1)^2?$ (Perhaps the intention was to define $Df(x) = (x-1)^2f''(x).$)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems badly posed to me. Perhaps it should be stated this way: Let $\mathcal P$ be the set of all polynomials. For $f\in \mathcal P,$ the function $(x-1)2f''(x)$ is a polynomial. So we can define a map $D: \mathcal P \to \mathcal P$ by setting $(Df)(x) = (x-1)3f''(x).$ Question 1: Is $D$ linear?

Now define $V$ as in the question. Question 2: Is $V$ a linear subspace of $\mathcal P?$ If so, does $D$ map $V$ into $V?$ (There is no need to introduce the notation $W.$)